# Ruby on Rails; division

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am fairly new to RoR. I have the following codes and uses a simple summation and division, but the value I get is 0. Not sure where I went wrong. Thx

```
- capacity_left = (total_capacity / total_amps) rescue 0
  h4 = "Capacity Reserve Left:  #{capacity_left} Hrs "

- total_amps = @site.equipment_inventories.sum {|e| e.equipment.amp.amp }
      h5 = "Total Amps: #{total_amps} amp"

- total_capacity = @site.dc_power_inventories.sum {|d| d.dc_power_supply.battery.capacity.capacity }
      h5 = "Total Capcity: #{total_capacity} Amp/hr"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing, but as a word of advice, the view layer is no place for writing such logic. This logic belongs in your model. This could be considered very bad Rails code.

Comment: also can you please explain what value is 0 ?

Comment: Hi Mohamad, you are correct, i will put them in the model. I just wanted to get this working. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip your code as below:

```
- total_amps = @site.equipment_inventories.sum {|e| e.equipment.amp.amp }
      h5 = "Total Amps: #{total_amps} amp"

- total_capacity = @site.dc_power_inventories.sum {|d| d.dc_power_supply.battery.capacity.capacity }
      h5 = "Total Capcity: #{total_capacity} Amp/hr"

- capacity_left = (total_capacity / total_amps) rescue 0
  h4 = "Capacity Reserve Left:  #{capacity_left} Hrs "
```

`total_capacity` and `total_amps` **MUST** be set before using.

Currently, as `total_capacity` and `total_amps` are not defined there value is `nil`.
Dividing `nil` by `nil` raises error `undefined method '/' for nil:NilClass` BUT since you rescued it using `rescue 0`, the output is always `0`.

Answer (score 2):

most probably both your variables are integers so you perform an integer division.

```
10 / 3 = 3
3 / 10 = 0
```

what you need to do is make a float cast, that can be done with the `to_f` method, and needs to be done to only one of the divisions operands.

so in your case

```
total_capacity / total_amps.to_f
```

or

```
total_capacity.to_f / total_amps
```

will both operate a float division and give a float result.

Comment: I have used your .to_f and helped resolve the 2nd issue. Thanks